# Arrastrar y Soltar Nodos en JavaFx

Tags: javafx

Quisiera hacer una aplicacion en javaFx que me permita arrastrar un Label de un lugar a otro dentro de un Pane, pero no logro encontrar guias claras en google, soluciones?

Answer (score 1):

**con eventos para mouse**

[image: moving node javafx]

hay que tener dos variables doubles como campos para que dos eventos distintos tengan acceso a ellas esas son las coordenadas iniciales x e y .

primero es `onMouseEnterd` cuando el cursor está dentro de `label`. si el cursor sale  gatilla `onMouseExited`. Si se presiona cualquier botón del mouse estando el cursor dentro de label se activa `onMousepressed`. Estando un botón apretado dentro de `label` y , además, se mueve el cursor  se  gatilla `setOnmouseDragged`  y , por último , al soltar el boton del mouse se gatilla `setOnMouseReleased`.Este código es una aplicación funcional en una sola clase de javafx para que pueda probar .

```
public class App extends Application {
    
    
     private double x ,y;
    
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        
        Label label = new Label("waiting");
        Pane pane = new Pane(label);
        label.setFont(new Font(40));
        
        label.setOnMouseEntered(e->
                
        {label.setText("ready");
        label.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
        e.consume();
        }
        );
        label.setOnMouseExited(e-> label.setText("waiting"));
        
        label.setOnMousePressed(e->{
        x=label.getLayoutX()-e.getSceneX();
        y=label.getLayoutY()-e.getSceneY();
        label.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
        label.setStyle("-fx-background-color:cyan");});
        
        label.setOnMouseDragged(e->{
        label.setLayoutX(e.getSceneX()+x);
        label.setLayoutY(e.getSceneY()+y);
        label.setText("moving");
        
        });
        label.setOnMouseReleased(e-> {label.setText("released");
        label.setStyle("-fx-background-color:transparent");
        }
        );
        
        
        var scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```